# Plotting a 3D surface plot with contour map overlay, using R

Tags: r, 3d, statistics, plot

I have a 3-tuple data set (X,Y,Z points) that I want to plot using R.

I want to create a surface plot from the data, and superimpose a contour map on the surface plot, so as to create the impression of the contour map being the "shadow" or projection from the surface plot. The contour map is to appear below the surface plot.

My data set looks somewhat like this:

```
Axis  |  Data Type
-------------------
X     |  Date value
Y     |  Float value
Z     |  Float value
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

*Edit:*

I just saw that you pointed out one of your dimensions is a date.  In that case, [have a look at Jeff Ryan's chartSeries3d](http://www.quantmod.com/examples/chartSeries3d/) which is designed to chart 3-dimensional time series.  Here he shows the yield curve over time:

[image: chartSeries example]

*Original Answer:*

As I understand it, you want a countour map to be the projection on the plane beneath the 3D surface plot.  I don't believe that there's an easy way to do this other than creating the two plots and then combining them.  You may [find the spatial view helpful for this](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html).

There are two primary R packages for 3D plotting: **[rgl](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/)** (or you can use the related [misc3d](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/) package) and **[scatterplot3d](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scatterplot3d/)**.

**rgl**

The rgl package uses OpenGL to create interactive 3D plots ([read more on the rgl website](http://rgl.neoscientists.org/)).  Here's an example using the `surface3d` function:

```
library(rgl)
data(volcano)
z <- 2 * volcano # Exaggerate the relief
x <- 10 * (1:nrow(z)) # 10 meter spacing (S to N)
y <- 10 * (1:ncol(z)) # 10 meter spacing (E to W)
zlim <- range(z)
zlen <- zlim[2] - zlim[1] + 1
colorlut <- terrain.colors(zlen,alpha=0) # height color lookup table
col <- colorlut[ z-zlim[1]+1 ] # assign colors to heights for each point
open3d()
rgl.surface(x, y, z, color=col, alpha=0.75, back="lines")
```

The alpha parameter makes this surface partly transparent.  Now you have an interactive 3D plot of a surface and you want to create a countour map underneath.  rgl allows you add more plots to an existing image:

```
colorlut <- heat.colors(zlen,alpha=1) # use different colors for the contour map
col <- colorlut[ z-zlim[1]+1 ] 
rgl.surface(x, y, matrix(1, nrow(z), ncol(z)),color=col, back="fill")
```

In this surface I set the heights=1 so that we have a plane underneath the other surface.  This ends up looking like this, and can be rotated with a mouse:

[image: 3D surface plot]

**scatterplot3d**

scatterplot3d is a little more like other plotting functions in R ([read the vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scatterplot3d/vignettes/s3d.pdf)).  Here's a simple example:

```
temp <- seq(-pi, 0, length = 50)
x <- c(rep(1, 50) %*% t(cos(temp)))
y <- c(cos(temp) %*% t(sin(temp)))
z <- c(sin(temp) %*% t(sin(temp)))
scatterplot3d(x, y, z, highlight.3d=TRUE,
 col.axis="blue", col.grid="lightblue",
 main="scatterplot3d - 2", pch=20)
```

In this case, you will need to overlay the images.  The R-Wiki [has a nice post on creating a tanslucent background image](http://wiki.r-project.org/rwiki/doku.php?id=tips:graphics-misc:translucency).

Comment: Thanks very much Shane. I think this is a very good starting point. Incidentally, you may have noticed that one of the axis is chronological (i.e. date). Do I need to do any manipulation before attempting to plot, or will R (or indeed the rgl package), handle the dates correctly?

Comment: Hi Shane, thank you very much for your help. You have given me sufficient ammunition to get stsrated with. If I encounter more specific problems, I will be back here with a more specific question.  I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: I wonder if that would work with point data too? I have lat/long data, each point with a certain value. Could I use this data as a "heightmap" too?