# interactive 3D diagrams in Flash? (not bars)

Tags: flash, 3d, diagram

I'm searching a (free or commercial) Flash component that can display 3D diagrams (**three axes**) and allow the user to interactively rotate the diagram.

The kind of diagram I'm talking about looks like this:

[image: an example of a 3D diagram]
<sub>(source: [amibroker.org](http://www.amibroker.org/userkb/wp-content/uploads/2007/08/io-3d.png))</sub>
.

The component would be used to display various three-dimensional arrays served **either from a server or JavaScript**.

I think I could write such a component myself, but really want to avoid to reinvent the wheel...

Any .swf available that does this?

Comment: You want to graph `two-dimensional datasets` with a 3d diagram?

Comment: Well, a two dimensional array of values.

Comment: @mrk was pointing you that with two-dimensional data (like date, visitors) you can build only two-dimensional chart like (http://bit.ly/q5wK6j).. and to be able to build three-dimensional chart you need third data attribute (like date, visitors, country). Well if one of your data values is date, you can split it to create 3rd dimension

Comment: well, just assume I have the right data structure for the chart above and I just need the Flash software to display it...

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://www.advance-media.com/) **commercial** product  which offers 3d surface chart. And I cannot find any other flash tools to create this kind of charts.

As possible solution, you can try to use [this tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896419/plotting-a-3d-surface-plot-with-contour-map-overlay-using-r), for creating static pictures on your server side (but as not r developer, I'm not sure if this possible), and after just load it as a static picture to show it to the user.

Also you can try to ask here at [stats SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) as written on their FAQ: "visualizing data" is on topic there.