# Overlay a map on top of a 3d surface map in r

Tags: r, rgl

I have created a 3d map using rgl.surface(), mainly following Shane's answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896419/plotting-a-3d-surface-plot-with-contour-map-overlay-using-r) post. Using my own data, I get this map

[image]

On top of this surface map, I would like to add a map of vegetation density such that I obtain something like this (obtained with the software Surfer):

[image]

Is it possible to do this with rgl, or for that matter any other package in r or is the only solution to have two maps like in Shane's answer?

Thank you.

*Edit:*

Following @gsk3's request, here is the code for this map:

```
library(rgl)

# Read the z (i.e. elevation) dimension from file
z1 = matrix(scan("myfile.txt"),nrow=256, ncol=256, byrow=TRUE)
#create / open x y (i.e. easting and northing coordinates) dimensions 
y=8*(1:ncol(z)) # Each point is 8 m^2
x=8*(1:nrow(z))

# See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896419/plotting-a-3d-surface-plot-with-contour-map-overlay-using-r for details of code below
zlim <- range(z)
zlen <- zlim[2] - zlim[1] + 1
colorlut <- terrain.colors(zlen,alpha=0) # height color lookup table
col <- colorlut[ z-zlim[1]+1 ] # assign colors to heights for each point
open3d()
rgl.surface(x,y,z)
```

I can't post the elevation code because there are 65536 (i.e. x*y=256*256) points but it is a matrix which looks like this

```
            [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5] 
[1,]    1513.708 1513.971 1514.067 1513.971 1513.875 
[2,]    1513.622 1513.524 1513.578 1513.577 1513.481
```

and so on.
Same for the vegetation density map, which is exactly the same format and for which I have a single value for each x*y point. I hope this makes things a bit clearer...?

*Edit 2, final version*

This is the map I have produced with R. I haven't got the legend on it yet but this is something I'll do at a later stage.

[image]

The final code for this is

```
library(rgl)
z1 = matrix(scan("myfile.txt"),nrow=256, ncol=256, byrow=TRUE)
# Multiply z by 2 to accentuate the relief otherwise it looks a little bit flat.
z= z1*2

#create / open x y dimensions
y=8*(1:ncol(z))
x=8*(1:nrow(z))

trn = matrix(scan("myfile.txt"),nrow=256, ncol=256, byrow=TRUE)
fv = trn*100
trnlim = range(fv)

fv.colors = colorRampPalette(c("white","tan4","darkseagreen1","chartreuse4")) ## define the color ramp
colorlut =fv.colors(100)c(1,seq(35,35,length.out=9),seq(35,75,length.out=30),seq(75,100,length.out=61))] 

# Assign colors to fv for each point
col = colorlut[fv-trnlim[1]+1 ] 
open3d()
rgl.surface(x,y,z,color=col)
```

Thank you very much to @gsk3 and @nullglob in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981631/sharp-break-in-color-palette-in-r) post for their help. Hope this post will help many others!

Comment: Interesting question but hard to answer without more info.  Please post your code and if you can your map somewhere, or at least describe it.  One possibility would be to put the vegetation fraction in as a color map, which I am pretty sure `rgl.surface()` would support....  Hard to say without more info though.

Comment: For info, I don't know how to put the vegetation fraction in as a color map as suggested by @gsk3 so it would be great if I could get an example of how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Just change all the color lines you're working with to work with the terrain matrix instead of the z matrix....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Modified above code to give an answer.  Note that terrain should be a matrix in the same format as the elevation matrix.  And I added a `,color` argument to your function call so it actually uses the color matrix you created.

```
library(rgl)

# Read the z (i.e. elevation) dimension from file
z1 = matrix(scan("myfile.txt"),nrow=256, ncol=256, byrow=TRUE)
#create / open x y (i.e. easting and northing coordinates) dimensions 
y=8*(1:ncol(z)) # Each point is 8 m^2
x=8*(1:nrow(z))

# Read the terrain types from a file
trn = matrix(scan("terrain.txt"),nrow=256, ncol=256, byrow=TRUE)

# See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896419/plotting-a-3d-surface-plot-with-contour-map-overlay-using-r for details of code below
trnlim <- range(trn)
trnlen <- trnlim[2] - trnlim[1] + 1
colorlut <- terrain.colors(trnlen,alpha=0) # height color lookup table
col <- colorlut[ trn-trnlim[1]+1 ] # assign colors to heights for each point
open3d()
rgl.surface(x,y,z,color=col)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm still not getting exactly what I want, but I think it is because the color code I gave you is not appropriate for what I want. I'll work it out thanks to your suggestion and I'll post my final code and map when I'm done.

Comment: Sure.  Thanks for committing to follow up here :-).  Hope the suggestions helped.