# Sharp break in color palette in r

Tags: r

I am creating a color palette with the following code:

```
library(rgl)
fv.colors = colorRampPalette(c("white","tan4","green"))
colorlut = terrain.colors(100)[c(100,95,90,85,80,75:30,25,20,15,14:1)]
col = colorlut[fv-trnlim[1]+1 ]
```

which gives this: (the color strip was created following the code provided [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NoJh.jpg))

[image]

What I would like to have instead is a strip of white at 0, as I currently have, but then a clean break at 0.01 where the palette would *start* at "tan4", rather than what it does now, i.e. go gradually from white to "tan4" (actually, at no point does it get as dark as tan4).

Apologies if it's a very simple answer but after many tries and much googling, I still can't work it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Those colors are just vectors.  Can you generate one going from whatever to white and another going from white to tan4 and combine them with `c()`?

Comment: Your code is not runnable. Please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to make a reproducible example.

Comment: @Joris Meyer Sorry, the full code is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901238/overlay-a-map-on-top-of-a-3d-surface-map-in-r). The problem is that the file I use to create fv is 256rows*256columns so I can't reproduce it here and creating an "ideal" file for example purposes would not work because the problems I have are with this specific file...

Comment: @gsk3 Could you please give me an example of what you're suggesting please, even though I'll have to adjust the colors myself. I still don't see what you mean....

Comment: Can't really provide an example without a reproducible problem....

Comment: Could it be that you can't get `colorlut` to give you `tan4` because `colorut` is defined using `terrain.colors` rather than `colorRampPalette` (where you explicitly request `tan4`)??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A small modification of your code seems to provide the answer you are after:

```
fv.colors = colorRampPalette(c("white","tan4","green")) ## define the color ramp
colorlut = fv.colors(100)[c(1,seq(50,100,length.out=99))] ## select colors to use
plot(0:1,0:1,type='n',xaxs='i',yaxs='i') ## define the plotting area
## illustrate the vector of colors using rectangles
rect(seq(0,0.99,0.01),rep(0,100),seq(0.01,1,0.01),rep(1,100),col = colorlut,border = NA)
box() ## make sure that the graph's frame is not covered up
```

*Edit:* The colours are a bit ugly to my eye, but you can adjust this by redefining the color ramp or the selection of colors from the ramp.

[image: Example of the colour chart]