# Make 3d surface

Tags: r, 3d, wolfram-mathematica, geometry-surface

I have data for `x` and `y` when `z=z1, z=z2 and z=z3`.
I'd like to plot the data on a 3d graph and approximate the curves with a 3d surface and to know the equation of the surface.
Will this be easier to implement on R or on Mathematica?
For instance how can I do it in R?
Thanks

Data (example):

```
For z=0
y   0.00    1.50    1.92    2.24
x   0.0000  0.0537  0.0979  0.2492

For z=2
y   0.00    2.21    2.83    3.07
x   0.0000  0.0173  0.0332  0.0655

For z=5
y   0.00    0.29    2.49    3.56
x   0.0000  0.0052  0.0188  0.0380
```

Comment: SO isn't really set up to answer "which is better/easier/faster/cooler/bigger/stronger" type questions...as they are inherently full of opinions and may change over time. For example, I use R all day every day, so doing this in R will almost certainly be easier *for me*. Can you rework your question to include some data points and ask for advice on plotting them in 3D? Then you can decide for your purposes if using R or mathematics is easier.

Comment: Edited the question and added data.

Comment: Great, good luck! [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896419/plotting-a-3d-surface-plot-with-contour-map-overlay-using-r) may be a useful starting point for you as it pertains to R.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Mathematica:

Suppose you have a set of points qt:

```
ListPointPlot3D[qt]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You could easily build an interpolation function:

```
Plot3D[Interpolation[qt][x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Ealuated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you need an explicit function model, you can propose one and calculate its parameters:

```
model = a x^2 + b y^2;
fit = FindFit[qt, model, {a, b}, {x, y}];
Show[Plot3D[model /. fit, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All], 
     ListPointPlot3D[qt, PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Medium], Red]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

And it is fairly easy to plot nice graphs:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @AlexBrown [Credit to @Heike](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4155/193)