# 3d surface plot in R with few datapoints

Tags: r, plot, 3d

I have 3 lists of 17 values each, x, y, and z. I want to create a 3d surface plot in R.

I found a lot of different explanations on how to do that, but somehow all speak about extrapolation, or drawing data from more data.

All I want is:

```
scatterplot3d(mean_reported,cent.close,effectsize)
```

with a surface connecting the points.

Is there an easy way doing this? Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plotting a 3D surface plot with contour map overlay, using R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896419/plotting-a-3d-surface-plot-with-contour-map-overlay-using-r)

Comment: The thread covers something different from this: they want to a countour map to be the projection on the plane beneath the 3D surface plot. 

Moreover, the thread uses syntax I don't get: why is the z value a matrix [1:87,1:67], while x and y aren't [1:67]? Also, the used package doesn't seem to provide a similar layout compared to the scatterplot3d (e.g., axes).